# Assigned input value is undefined since onChange is never triggered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I need a solution for following problem ...

When a user registers succesfully, he gets redirected to the login page with email input field filled out and focus on password field. (email is send over paramaters)

Now since onChange event was not triggered (because email was not typed) it's value returns undefined and therefore login fails.

Is there a way to get around this?

You can found my code below

```
const email = queryString.parse(location.search).email; // returns email correctly
```

The following is a component so each attribute is set as `name={props.name} value={props.value}` etc

```
const handleChange = (name, value) => {
    setData((prev) => ({ ...prev, [name]: value }));
};

<InputField name="email" type="email" onChange={handleChange} value={email ? email : ""}
```

So when everything is typed manually, `data` gets updated as expected and everything works fine, but when redirected from register to login with the field filled out through `email` variable, then email in data will be undefined.

Is there a way to trigger onChange when email is placed as a value inside the input field?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `handleChange` is not getting the parameters of `name` and `value`

You can try something like: (Assuming name is a variable defined)

```
<InputField name="email" type="email" onChange={(e, {value}) => handleChange(name, value)} value={email ? email : ""}
```

Comment: Sinan thanks for reply but this doesn't seem to work ...

Comment: Ok i fixed it myself this way :)

`useEffect(() => {
    const getVal = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='email']")[0].value;
    if (getVal) setData((prev) => ({ ...prev, email: getVal }));
  }, []); `

Answer (score 0):

I make a simple code, but I don't konw what actually you need, you can check on :

[image: Edit TextField selectionStart]

Or

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Sample = (props) => {
  // const query = window.location.search;
  const query = window.location;
  const [value, setValue] = useState(query);

  const handleValueOnChange = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };

  console.log(query);
  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={handleValueOnChange} value={value} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Sample;
```

Hope to help you .

Comment: Thanks for lookin in to it Jay! I fixed it myself using something simple. Thanks again :)